# Telebot Python. Как пользователю разрешить вводить только числами?

Tags: python, telebot

не могу найти информацию как разрешить пользователю вводить только числа. int(message.text) выдает ошибку. Буду признателен тем, кто решит помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете повлиять на ввод пользователя. Но можете проверить, что он ввёл число методом `isdigit` или написать обработчик исключительно для чисел.

***Пример:***

```py
@bot.message_handler(regexp=r"\d+")
```

***Пример:***

```py
text = '256'
print(text.isdigit())  # True

text = 'Hello, World!'
print(text.isdigit())  # False
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Уже второй раз выручаете)